# Can you set keep aligned to off by default on desktop?  

Tags: 10.10

Can you set "keep aligned" to off by default on desktop?

Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

Right click the desktop and you can uncheck "Keep Aligned"

Comment: I have done this but after reboot it is back to the default of being set to aligned again. I thought maybe there was a way to keep this as unchecked by default. Thanks for the reply.